# Plot log function

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am a beginner in Mathematica, I want to plot this log((x + y)/y). I did some attempts such as below but it kept showing an error as below. Would you please tell me what is wrong in the syntax?

LogLogPlot[{log[(x + y)/y]}, {x, 0.1, 3}, {y, 0.1, 3}]

LogLogPlot::nonopt: Options expected (instead of {y,0.1,3}) beyond position 2 in LogLogPlot[{log[(x+y)/y]},{x,0.1,3},{y,0.1,3}]. An option must be a rule or a list of rules.

Comment: Do you want a 3D LogPlot? Then [this](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/208038) might help you. At least the *Mathematica* versions I know do not have a 3D LogLogPlot build in.

Comment: as a note, if the function name does not contain 3D or Contour or Density, but just Plot like ListPlot etc, it is most likely only for 2D

Answer (score 0):

Referencing this [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/34668/how-can-i-plot-implicit-equations) and [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5266/363).

```
pl = Normal@ContourPlot[Log[(x + y)/y],
     {x, 0.1, 3}, {y, 0.1, 3}, PlotPoints -> 100];

ListLogLogPlot[Cases[pl, Line[a_, b___] :> a, Infinity],
 Joined -> True, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> All,
 AspectRatio -> 1, PlotStyle -> ColorData[1][1]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may use [`Plot3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot3D.html) with the [`ScalingFunctions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ScalingFunctions.html) option.

```
Plot3D[Log[(x + y)/y], {x, 0.1, 3}, {y, 0.1, 3},
 ScalingFunctions -> {None, None, "Log"},
 MeshFunctions -> {#3 &},
 BoxRatios -> Automatic]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Click and drag the plot to rotate.  Also note that in the Wolfram Language is case sensitive so it is `Log` and not `log`.

Hope this helps.